# Why isn't the Nginx Gzip Precompression module working?

Tags: nginx, gzip

I'm currently trying to set up Nginx to serve all of my static files. Since they will not be changed very frequently at all I want to us the gzip_static module to allow me to pre-gzip copies of my files to save some cpu time and allow better compression.

I Compiled Nginx with `--with-http_gzip_static_module` and set it up so that it is serving my static files, no problems so far. I wanted to test and make sure that the static gzipping was actually working, so I made two files, `test.txt` and `test.txt.gz`. The first line of each of the files says whether they were gzipped, and then there's a newline and 256 random characters (different betweeen the two files).

I've read that the modification time of the file and it's gzipped counterpart should be the same, and I've tried both of the following:

```
touch test.*
touch -r test.txt test.txt.gx
```

On my local machine, I'm testing with curl:

```
curl $URL/test.txt
```

This works fine, I get back the version that I didn't pre-compress, but when I do this:

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" $URL/test.txt | gunzip
```

I *also* get back the version I didn't precompress. I tried setting `gzip off` in my `nginx.conf`, but it doesn't make a difference. I've also re-compiled Nginx with `--without-http_gzip_module` and that doesn't seem to make a difference either, Nginx *still* gzips things itself on the fly.

I'm quite new to Nginx, but I'm really at a loss here.

Here is the output of `./nginx -V`

```
built by gcc 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) 
configure arguments: --sbin-path=$SOMEPATH/nginx --prefix=$SOMEPATH --user=$ME --group=$MYGROUP --with-http_gzip_static_module --without-http_gzip_module
```

And here is my `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    gzip_static on;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    access_log  logs/access.log;
    server {
        listen       XXXX;
        server_name  foo.bar.com;
        location / {
            root   html;
        }
        error_page  404 404.html;
        error_page   500 502 503 504 50x.html;
    }
}
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't mention this in your question, but I have it on good authority that you are running Nginx proxied behind another Nginx on a shared host. ;)

At the time I'm writing this, Nginx's gzip modules use HTTP 1.1 by default, but Nginx can only use HTTP 1.0 when communicating with back-end servers, so the solution is to set `gzip_http_version` in your `nginx.conf`, like so:

```
gzip_http_version 1.0;
```

Restart your Nginx after making that change, and you should be in business.

Comment: Amazing! How did you know this?